# Same function called in different buttons and both are giving different output in Reactjs, javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, state

This is my code

```js
const [datatable, setDatatable] = useState({
  columns: [
    {
      label: 'Title',
      field: 'title',
      width: 200,
      attributes: { ariacontrols: 'DataTable', 'aria-label': 'Name' },
    },
    { label: 'Language', field: 'language', width: 500 },
    { label: 'Description', field: 'description', width: 200 },
    { label: '', field: 'publish', sort: 'asc', width: 300 },
  ],
  rows: [{ _id: '', title: '', description: '', language: '', publish: '' }],
});

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('/admin/challenges').then((response) => {
    data = response.data;
    data.map((item) => {
      item.publish = (
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            viewPage(item._id);
          }}
          size="small"
          variant="outlined"
          color="primary"
        >
          view
        </Button>
      );
    });
    setDatatable({
      ...datatable,
      rows: data,
    });
  });
}, []);

// Event handler for button

const viewPage = () => {
  console.log(datatable);
};
```

And I created seperate button and passed the same function 'viewPage' as a handler.

```js
return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={viewPage}>Hello</button>
    <div>
      //a datatable('state datable is passed as props') where each row has button and its event handler is 'viewPage'                  
      <MDBDataTableV5
        hover
        entriesOptions={[5, 20, 25]}
        entries={5}
        pagesAmount={4}
        data={datatable}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

But When I clicked the button both are showing different results, the button I declared in table is giving me only initial state as output, but the other button is giving correct updated state.
So I am confused by its working. So what I am missing here and why???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably due to adding the button in **useEffect** hook. The **viewPage** function uses **datatable** variable. You would probibly need to add **viewPage** to to dependencies of the useEffect. But this wouldt work because you would make the request multiple time.
You can store the result you got from the useEffect hook api call into a state variable and map when returning jsx.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the event handler redefined when the render function called.
So re-rendered elements have a new eventHandler function and un-rendered elements have an old event handler function. You can use the arrow function or the callback function.

```
<button onClick={() => {
  console.log(datatable)
}} >Hello</button>
```

Comment: If you want to use arrow function you can change the onClick part like below.
```
<button onClick={() => {
  console.log(datatable)
}} >Hello</button>
```

Comment: Hi @anas_m__!
Are you still struggling with this problem?
If so, try to use `self.viewPage(item.id)`
And let me know if it works or not.